# Set resource standard rate in Project Server 2013 with CSOM

Tags: development, csom, project-server

I found no properties nor any method for setting the standard rate of an `EnterpriseResource` for Project Server 2013 with C# and CSOM. Searching online I didn't find anything specific on enterprise resources, standard rate, and CSOM. Does anybody know how to set the standard rate for an enterprise resource?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried looking in `EnterpriseResource.CustomFIelds` or `EnterpriseResource.FieldValues`. Just a hunch

Comment: @Mike thanks for the tip. Unfortunately `CustomFields` and `FieldValues` are specific to custom fields that have values set for the resource (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.projectserver.client.enterpriseresource_di_pj14mref_members.aspx)). Unfortunately, the standard rate is not a custom field and, in my case, neither has its value set for the resource (being the resource a new one).

Comment: You may have to use the web service PSI, modifying a dataset and going from there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg203009.aspx

Comment: @Mike, yeah, I guess it's the only way. [The only question and answer I found](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/786d559f-5568-4afe-b518-b6b1cdd151bb/is-it-possible-to-update-standard-rate-for-an-enterprise-resource-using-csom?forum=projectonline) go in the PSI direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, the property you are trying to set may not be available via client side. You may have to use the web service PSI, modifying a dataset and going from there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg203009.aspx